# How can I pipe wget/curl output to check whether it contains specific word?

Tags: curl, sed, awk, grep, wget

I'm trying to download a huge number of consecutive files from a website, but I only need those that contain a specific word. What I'm doing now: I'm downloading all files like this:

```sh
wget http://host/file/{0..100000}.html
```

What I need is to check the output, and if it contains "phrase", download it to my hard drive. Please point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way that you can check the contents of a file/web page without downloading it -- even if it's just a temporary download. An easy workaround for this would be to have a script that downloads the file, checks for whatever keyword, and if there, keep the file otherwise discard it. Something like this:

```
for i in `seq 100000`; 
do 
   wget http://host/file/$i.html
   grep KEYWORD $i.html
   if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] 
   then
       echo "File $i.html was kept" 
   else
       echo "File $i.html will be deleted"
       rm -f $i.html
   fi
done;
```

**Just as a disclaimer: I did not test the above script, but it should be a good enough of an example.